# Prime subfield enveloping algebra in Magma

Tags: magma-cas

Given a matrix group *G* $\leq$ *GL*(*d*, *K*), I can create the subalgebra of **Mat**$_{d}$(*K*) consisting of all *K*-linear combinations of the elements of *G* using the MatrixAlgebra<*K*, *d* | *L*> constructor. I can't, however, create the subalgebra of **Mat**$_{d}$(*K*) consisting of all *K$_{0}$*-linear combinations of the elements of *G* where _K_$_{0}$ is the prime subfield of *K*. Is there a way of creating such an object in **MAGMA**?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this with an alternate MatrixAlgebra usage;
put

```
A = MatrixAlgebra(K,d | L);
```

then to convert it over the basefield put

```
B := MatrixAlgebra(A, PrimeField(K));
```

this will give, as a second return value, a map to convert over just specific matrices if you like.

Comment: I'll give that a try and thanks for the response!